# Allocation of 2D arrays (matrices) in C?

Tags: c, arrays, matrix

I am working on C, specifically on creating a matrix using pointers, and one thing that confuses me is that in a 2D array that `matrix[i][j]` is equal to

```
*(*(matrix+i)+j)
```

Does this mean that the element located, in say, the position `[3][3]` is given by `*(*(0+3)+3))`?

More specifically, I'm coding a matrix in C by using the following code:

```
  double** makeMatrix(unsigned int rows, unsigned int cols)
{
  unsigned int i;
  double** matrix;
  matrix = (double** ) malloc(rows * sizeof(double *));
   if (!matrix) { return NULL; }/* failed */
     for (i = 0; i < rows; i++)
     {
      matrix[i] = (double *) malloc(cols*sizeof(double));
      if (!matrix[i])
      return NULL; 
     }
return matrix;
}
```

So, allocating memory to each i'th element within the array - is this the reason that we get *(*(matrix+i)+j) for the [i][j] - due to the fact that each element has its own memory block?

Comment: Please search on the site before post a question. http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bc%5D+2d+matrices

Comment: Before you burst in with arrogant retorts, I have 'searched on the site' for the question and nothing matched with specifically what I'm asking.

Comment: Please clarify what you are asking then (e.g., how is the array defined?). Your post is a bit of a mess, and right now, not really useful. Have a look at this page for some introduction into the markdown used here: http://stackoverflow.com/editing-help

Comment: format your que correctly!!

Comment: There is no 2D array in your code and nothig which can point to one.

Comment: I've just removed an answer, since you edited your question to include an example with a dynamically allocated array of arrays (which some call a jagged array).   The problem is, a 2D array and a dynamically allocated array of dynamically allocated arrays, although having some similarities of behaviour, are very different things.   Get clear what you are asking about - by editing/changing the question as you did, you successfully wasted my time.

Comment: @Peter: A dynamically allocated array and a multidimensional array are no contradictions. You can have a 2D array dynamically allocated as you can have an "array of pointers to arrays" statically allocated.

Comment: I think you've misunderstood my comment, Olaf.   I have not suggested any contradiction.

Comment: @Peter: But that's what you wrote: " The problem is, a 2D array and a dynamically allocated array of dynamically allocated arrays, although ..."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In C, there are no multidimensional arrays to the "true" sense (like in LISP, C# or C++/CLI). Rather than that, what you can declare is array of arrays (or array of pointers, where each pointer is assigned by `malloc` etc.). For instance:

```
int matrix[2][3];
```

defines two-elements array, where each element is of type array of three `int`s.

Now, when you refer to an ultimate array element, you need to *first* derefence into that inner array, *then* into the `int` object:

```
int value = matrix[2][3];
```

which is equivalent to:

```
int value = (*(*(matrix + 2) + 3));
```

Comment: Multidimensional array you wrote about (which is as true as it can be in machine with linear address space), is not the same what OP was asking about (pointer to array of pointers to arrays or jagged array).

Comment: @user694733: Yes I know but the general idea is the same and the array of arrays is just simpler to explain.

Comment: @user694733: So it is answering about what OP wants or what it implemented. As you say yourself: what OP implemented is not a 2D array, so I think the answer is fine. Although I disagree with the "no multidimensional arrays". It is just a different way of writing than `int i[rows, cols];`.

Comment: I'd still call this multidimensional array. Just a different way of writing. Things are a bit more complicated in languages where the length is stored in the array-object.

Comment: `(*(*(matrix + 2)) + 3);` should be `*(*(matrix + 2) + 3);`, otherwise you dereference twice and add 3 to it.

Comment: @mch: Fixed, thank you for spotting this. I always hate these nasty parentheses.

Comment: I still don't see why this would not be a N-D array. The main difference is the syntax and that the other languages store the lengths inside the object. Which is not even true for a 1D array in C. So either it should be "C does not have true arrays (including 1D)" or it makes no sense at all. Where do you draw the line?

Comment: @Olaf: I guess it is about that, some languages offer "direct" and single data type for multidimensional array. For example, in the C++/CLI, you could write something like `array<int, 2>^ matrix`. Here, you don't care how array is structured, you just conveniently access its elements like `matrix[2, 3]`.

Comment: @GrzegorzSzpetkowski: As I wrote, this is not related to the number of dimensions, then, but how much overhead/comport the language provides when dealing with them (pass lengths explicitly/implicitly). Now, C is very basic, of course (that's why we use it for specific fields) and follows the "keep it explicit" approach. Btw. C++ (not sure about C#) is a very bad example, as e.g. `array` (and `vector`) are not standard types, but provided by the library already. You can easily do the same in C - just with a different syntax (the index-operator is the same as a function call).

Comment: ... a better example would be Pascal.

Comment: @Olaf: In C++/CLI (not C++) the `array` is first class citizen data type (see [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ts4c4dw6.aspx)). It just happens to be the same name that one of the ISO C++ STL containers (which is kind of bad choice of name IMHO).

Comment: @GrzegorzSzpetkowski: I don't talk about proprietary extensions which are not portable, but standard C++. Sorry I missed the "/CLI" part. IDK this, but if it has the same name/signature as the standard container, it makes the whole language incompatible - again. Yes, a very bad idea and the classic "embrace" way to damage a language (see J++).

Answer (score 1):

`a[i]` is a [syntactic sugar](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Syntactic_sugar) for `*(a + i)`. That means that `a[3][3]` is equivalent to `*(*(a + 3) + 3)`.

One other thing is notable, `3[a]` is equivalent to `*(3 + a)` which is `*(a + 3)`, which is `a[3]`.

Comment: I understand that arrays are assigned in such in C that we return a pointer that points to the first element, and add i to get the i'th element, but I suppose what I don't understand is when you get the 2D array. Why isn't it, say, *(a+i) + *(a+j)?

Comment: The answer is wrong for the code of OP! Identical syntax does not imply identical semantics. One of the problems with this undying missconception is exactly that there are two very different things with the same syntax.

Comment: @Olaf when I answered the question, there was no any code in it, an edit has been made. The question was "does this mean that the element located the position [3][3] is given by *(*(0+3)+3))?"

Comment: @AinJalut There are actually no arrays in C, there are just pointers. You can treat 2D array as pointer to piece of memory, which holds pointers to pieces of memory, each of them holding data.

Comment: @Anton: So either you should roll back the question (questions must not change after an answer has been posted). However, I'm strongly against it this time, because the original was missing vital parts. You should have asked for clarification instead of providing a too early answer. Or edit your answer.